# Ubuntu static routes location

Tags: routing

I have Ubuntu 18.04 server wich can't boot because HDD problems and I didn't succeed to fix it.
The HDD is readable and I can open it from Ubuntu usb drive for example.
So, is it possible to find where is stored static routes of the "dead" ubuntu and to put in in my new server?
Thank you!

Comment: What is in: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.